# 2004 Chevy Malibu won't start after changing timing chain, crank sensor and ignition module and coil pack

Tags: chevrolet, starting, malibu, cranks-wont-run

I've changed the timing chain because it jumped time in my 2004 Chevy Malibu 2.2 liter.  I've also changed the ignition module, crank sensor and coil pack, but it still won't start.

Comment: I can't find your engine listed as an interference engine, that's good.  You may want to walk through each step of reassembly and validate that you have everything correct.  That sanity check will help you mentally as you push forward with your troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

There is much to be said here;  You first should have done an electrical connection **probe test** to know if your **fuel pump** is operating, your **sparks** are sparking, your **coil is sparking**, your **injectors are igniting**, your distributor components are working, == the vehicle **timing is correct**, your **starter** is kicking, your **Fuel Injection Main Relay**, **Coolant Temperature Sensor**, or the **O2 Sensor**.  I know it's confusing and sounds like a lot of work but a couple of hours could save you a couple of hundred.  do yourself a favor!  buy a cheap $35. - $50. OBD Scanner before you do anything else.  Plug it in and start from there.  In the meantime watch the following video.  I picked it out specifically for you.   I hope it helps.  Good Luck !   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1L4nB2NdA0U

Answer (score 0):

You say the chain jumped timing. Was the car running when you disassembled it? Or did you have a tow truck bring it in? If you were stranded you may have damaged cylinder head valves. Do a compression test.

Comment: The EcoTec engine and the 3.1L LG/L8 were not interference engines. It shouldn't have bent the valves.... Unless something very catastrophic happened.

Answer (score 0):

Was the engine running before you disassembled it, yes or no?
Most of 2.0, 2.2 and 2.4  16 valve small engines ARE interference.
If after you assembled it and you missed on the timing and cranked the engine
with just one of the camshafts out of timing you ruined the head.
Do a compression test.  You can rent or borrow the tool.